# Windows IoT intercept Debug.Write messages without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

Is it possible to read messages from Debug.Write method without Visual Studio?
Does anyone know of such a tool?

In NETMF is the possibility in .Net Micro Framework Deployment Tool. 
[image: Image from http://kodfilemon.blogspot.com]

Unfortunatelly Iot Dashboard does not have such a tool.

Comment: Whoops, I just suggested some desktop debuggers, but those won't work on Win IoT, sorry about that.

Comment: It turns out [there is a way to debug your Win IoT app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/windbg) by using WinDbg, hopefully that will do ya fine.

Comment: Thank You. So it is possible but I'm using Raspberry Pi. Reading debug messages via serial connection in IoT device... rate how it sounds :) Additionally WinDbg is part of a large package of tools.

A solution that suggests Rita looks better but I was hope that exist something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect with your device over network, you can [use ETW viewer in Device Portal](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/10/using-device-portal-to-view-debug-logs-for-uwp/#DtkL5dr9xrhPYIki.97). Configuring the logging channel and using LoggingChannel.LogMessage(), you can printf-debugging for your code.